# Java - Reading €-sign from editor results in â?¬

Tags: java, utf-8

I have written a tiny program that reads in some bill and sums up all the values. The program reads in the bill from a .txt-file (I am using Windows by the way, if that is important).

Previously everything worked perfectly but no it does not anymore because reading in € results in â?¬.
Could anyone tell me why that is and how to fix it?
(The java version that I have been using might have changed since I wrote the program, currently it is java 16, if that is of any help).

A fragment of the program is the following:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class RechnungAuswerter {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
            System.out.println("Calculation of "+ args[0]);
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(args[0]);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            while(line != null){
                System.out.println(line);
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(count + "€");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying, you are not able to read € from the file or its not printed correctly on conole ?

Comment: Tell `FileReader` what character set the file is encoded in; it doesn't appear to be your default one.

Comment: Looks like the file is UTF-8 but it's being read like it was using CP-1252 or something. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake

Comment: posted code should not compile without error - anyway, try `new FileReader(args[0], StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`

Comment: If I update the code, changing the FileReader- construction-line to FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(args[0], StandardCharsets.UTF_8); and adding java-nio as imports, it is still incapable of dealing with the € sign and returns ? to the console.